# Easiest way to browse iPhone filesystem

Tags: ios, filesystem

What method of browsing the root filesystem is least likely to make any modifications to it?  Hooking to a pc is an option.  Jailbreaking is not an option for this question.

Comment: You cannot access the root filesystem without jailbreaking the device. At best, you can only access parts of your mobile account but not root.

Comment: If your device is still iOS 6, plugging it in on Ubuntu 12.04 (maybe earlier Ubuntu versions too) will allow you to browse the entire AFP file system. I haven't tried this with iOS 7 and I don't think it works, but maybe some upgrades will help.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat - This is interesting. How can I access an iPhone in iOS 6 on a Mac?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any way to do it on Mac.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat I was able to retrieve soundtrack to NFS Shift 2 Unleashed written specifically for iOS this way. There are 5 remixed songs that are not in desktop version of the game and you cannot find it anywhere on the internet, at all. Good old days.

Answer (score 22):

Despite the fact Steve Jobs [didn't support this idea](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/06/steve-jobs-on-the-file-system/) because it's making things complicated for the users, there are some apps which will allow you to do so.

There is [i-FunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) which allows you to browse through your iPhone files on your Mac. And if you're a Windows user, you've more options. There is [iPhoneBrowser](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/05/31/iphonebrowser-browse-your-iphones-file-system/) or [iPhone Folders](http://www.troublefixers.com/open-browse-iphone-filesystem-from-my-computer-with-iphone-folders/).
All of these solutions will allow you to browse the iPhone file systems using your computer.

If you want to be able to browse on your iPhone yourself, I'm afraid I only know one solution, called [iFile](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/eu.heinelt.ifile). But this is only accessible on a jailbroken device...

Comment: iFunbox just crashes when I launch it.

Comment: The older version of iFunBox works, but does not give me access to the full file system. I am looking for a Safari file, but no access.

Comment: @Michiel, What's the closest to iFile without jailbreaking?

Comment: Your link to iPhoneBrowser is broken, and iPhone Folders doesn't work on Windows 10. i-FunBox on Windows just keeps telling me to install iTunes even though it's already installed.

Answer (score 10):

### Sorry to break the news...but...

You cannot reach the root directory without something being compromised on the phone itself. You may be able to access your music/photos/ringtones, but the root directory is off-limits to non-jailbroken iPhone users.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using DiskAid which is a good file manager to access the iPhone file system from your desktop Mac or Windows. You can connect to your device through Wi-Fi or USB, access your App contents, Music, SMS etc. Transfers are stable and reliable, for example if you disconnect your USB cable during a transfer the transfer will automatically continue via Wi-Fi.

http://www.digidna.net/diskaid

The root file system is accessible in DiskAid but as the other similar solutions only if your device is jailbroken.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ], especially the part about self-promotion. Also, "best" is a relative term, maybe you can elaborate a bit on the features you like and use?

Comment: iMazing, which replaces the older DiskAid product, looks to be pretty solid -- although it carries a US $30 price tag after a 15-day free trial.

Comment: This link gives iMazing. But iMazing does not work on Mac OS X 10.6.8. Too bad!

Comment: @3313code, can it really be accessed by Wifi?

Answer (score -1):

Theres more than 1 option. Download dropcopy on your iPhone. Press the circle. Press preview. Press Root Filesystem. There you go! You don't have to be jail broken.

Comment: FYI - I believe this requires iOS 8.

Comment: the drop copy doesn't work,
i am currently working on a way to make it possible to install AFC2(Apple File Conduit 2) without jailbreak that will allow you access to root files without jailbreak

Comment: What is "dropcopy"?