# Editing/removing hostfile on jailed iPhone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, hosts

So guys I've done a very silly thing. I've installed a tweak that blocks ad websites, but apparently it blocks every connection on the internet(things using DNS, but now all the things use it)
I only realised this after restarting my phone(silly me thought that restarting will solve the problem). Pretty much my iPhone is a brick because I can't even connect to the http://ppq.apple.com (again it uses DNS) to validate the developer certificate. So there is no way running yalu again or any other code.
So is there a way to ignore/delete/edit that hostfile?
I want the restore to be my last resort(hopefully to iOS 10.2(I have the blobs saved))

Comment: If you have a terminal installed on your phone you could easily delete the host file which is located at `private/etc/hosts`. But you don't want to delete it entirely. You want to restore it to the way it was before.

Answer (score 2):

The `hosts` file is located at `/private/etc/hosts` which cannot be accessed on a non-jailbroken iOS device. There is simply no way to do it. More information on why this is and what occurs during the jailbreak process can be found on my answer on [Can you apply jailbreak tweaks to a non-jailbroken device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45073/18387)

Comment: Indeed, hosts can't be edited without being in a jailbroken state, however I'm also curious about how OP can't run yalu. I didn't know yalu needed a network connection? Or have I missed something else?

Comment: @grgarside I'm fairly certain that it doesn't need a network connection since it's all just public/private key cryptography. I'm trying to think what the issue could really be. I'll test it out on my Pangu semi-untethered device by putting it on airplane mode.

Comment: @grgarside I rebooted with airplane mode on, was still in airplane mode with it booted, and I opened Pangu just fine and successfully performed the jailbreak (I'm using the same Cydia Impactor method that Yalu uses).

Comment: Yup exactly what I expected. Perhaps OP is using the 7 day cert which has expired? But then I didn't know you needed network on the device (only on Cydia Impactor).

Comment: @grgarside You shouldn't need network connectivity except for with Cydia Impactor. I'll take out my SIM card through the whole process of signing it, etc, just in case.

Comment: I've installed yalu using xcode, if that matters, and it says that the cert needs to be verified, even to me it seems wired

Comment: @grgarside Just tried it with my SIM card removed the whole time. Worked just fine.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson using cydia impactor?

Comment: @StefanScoarta Correct. Maybe Xcode doesn't something different than Impactor.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson looks like it's the same thing still ask me to verify the binary

Comment: Eh I'll just try a restore using 9e4c nonce, I've heard that you can get a nonce collision on a iPhone5s and I have it saved

Comment: @StefanScoarta That must be new in iOS 10. I can't think of any way to fix this other than to restore. Sorry. The best tutorial for the Prometheus tool for restoring to iOS 10.2 is here: http://www.ipodhacks142.com/how-to-restore-to-ios-10-2-unsigned-using-prometheus-on-iphone-ipod-touch-or-ipad/